# OptiPNG is not optimizing png files for Google Page Speed Insight

Tags: optimization, png, google-pagespeed

I've CentOS 6 and I've installed OptiPNG 0.6.4 (the only available on CentOS).
When I optimize images, I run this command:

```
find . -regex ".*\.\(png\)" -exec optipng -o7 -preserve '{}' \+
```

For OptiPNG my images are optimized, but when I run Google Page Speed Insight it complains about my PNGs are not optimized.

Should I use another command?
Should I install a newer version of OptiPNG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I find out what was the problem.
The problem was the version of my software that didn't support loss less.
So I installed the latest version ([Download](http://www.mediafire.com/download/9bsat1t6frrkqrj/optipng-0.7.4.tar.gz)), this is how you can do it:

```
#Uploads the tar.gz file
yum install wget
wget dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
tar -xvzf optipng-0.7.4.tar.gz
cd optipng-0.7.4
./configure && make && make install
```

Finally, when you have installed properly Optipng, you can run the longest Optipng command that makes Google stop complaining about your images. Here you are:

```
find . -regex ".*\.\(png\)" -exec /usr/local/bin/optipng -o7 -preserve -strip all '{}' \+
```

Comment: The key here is `-strip all`.  Google doesn't like to see small images with lots of useless metadata.

Comment: You can see the key in my answer

Comment: Melini Yes, clearly.  My point is that your explanation is fails to explain why it is the newer version is required. I.e. what that argument does.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know how Pagespeed determines whether images are optimized or not, but I did get a complaint about one image; then I ran

```
pngcrush -ow -reduce -rem alla file.png
```

uploaded the new "file.png" and Pagespeed was happy with it.

Disclaimer: I wrote pngcrush (and a friend wrote optipng as a fork of pngcrush)